# JSON does not store full data when storing in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a table in SQL Server 2016 and I want to convert in into JSON:

My query is:

```
SELECT * FROM TEST FOR JSON AUTO
```

Above query converts all the data in table test into single row.

When I check the length of the data which I got from the above query: It was 6 millions

But when I do this:

```
;WITH x(a) as 
(
    SELECT * FROM test FOR JSON AUTO
)
SELECT a INTO #b FROM x

select * from #b
```

It only returns 50000 characters not the full data.

How to get all the data in my temp table.

Comment: I assume you're copying from SSMS? The maximum characters you can copy (for a single value) from SSMS is 65,535 characters (and that isn't the default setting). If you want the full dataset, don't use SSMS to copy it. Use a `BULK` operation to export it.

Comment: I am using SSMS, what if I change the default settings of 65,535 characters? Will that work in my case

Comment: 65,535 is the default value, it's lower, however, that is the **maximum** value you can have. You will never be able to copy 6Million characters, from a single value, from SSMS.